# :hover only on path's fill in SVGs?

Tags: css, svg, path, hover, fill

Is it possible to only have the CSS `:hover` fire when on actually within the path? My path doesn't take up the whole div, and I only want it to fire when within the actual path. I figure only having it done when on the path's fill would be sufficient, but I'm open to other ideas. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157122/css-change-fill-color-on-hover-svg-path ?

Comment: Possibly also related to `pointer-events`, see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616233/css-hover-sometimes-doesnt-work-on-svg-paths