# How to change svg fill on hover

Tags: css, svg, hover, fill

I'm trying to get the hover to work on the **X Close Button**.

The hover works stand alone, by itself:

**Seen Here:** https://jsfiddle.net/02ke4r5v

And in the snippet I provided.

When I place it in my code it does not work.

**Seen Here:** https://jsfiddle.net/hnba7z0d/

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fadeInExit 2s forwards 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit:hover .exitHover {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
    <g id="exit">
      <title>exit</title>
      <path class="exitHover" d="m-143 0a143 143 0 1 1 286 0 143 143 0 0 1 -286 0m128-112a113 113 0 0 0 -97 97h97zm-97 127a113 113 0 0 0 97 97v-97zm127 97a113 113 0 0 0 97 -97h-97zm97-127a113 113 0 0 0 -97 -97v97z" transform="rotate(45)" fill="red" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: The code you posted in your question does not have that problem. You should have made that clear. I see there is a problem in your fiddle though.

Comment: I just updated the link: https://jsfiddle.net/hnba7z0d/ The hover is not working in the code.

Comment: The hover works stand alone, by itself: Seen Here: https://jsfiddle.net/02ke4r5v/ When I place it in my code it does not work. Seen Here: https://jsfiddle.net/hnba7z0d/

Comment: I just updated the post.

Comment: Thank you.  You might as well remove the code block from the question, because it does not show the problem. So serves no real purpose.  The preferred way to cut doesn you code into a [mcve] similar to what I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are styling the original exit SVG on hover.  That particular one should work.

However all the other buttons that use `<svg><use>` will not work because when you hover over them, the mouse event doesn't get passed through to the original one (that `use` points to).

Instead, you should attach the hover rule to the `<svg><use>` elements instead.
You can apply a style to them, and it will inherited by the original used instance.

```css
.exit {
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}


.exit:hover svg {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<p>original</p>
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
    <g id="exit">
      <title>exit</title>
      <circle class="exitCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="144" fill="transparent"/>
      <path class="exitHover" d="m-143 0a143 143 0 1 1 286 0 143 143 0 0 1 -286 0m128-112a113 113 0 0 0 -97 97h97zm-97 127a113 113 0 0 0 97 97v-97zm127 97a113 113 0 0 0 97 -97h-97zm97-127a113 113 0 0 0 -97 -97v97z" transform="rotate(45)" fill="red" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>

<p>&lt;use&gt;</p>
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
    <use href="#exit" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

However if you try this, you will see that it still doesn't work.  That's because the value of `fill` is being over-ridden by the `fill="red"` attribute that the path already has.

The solution is to remove the `fill="red"` attribute and give that path a default red style using CSS.

```
.exit svg {
  fill: red;
}

.exit:hover svg {
  fill: green;
}
```

```css
.exit {
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}


.exit svg {
  fill: red;
}

.exit:hover svg {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<p>original</p>
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
    <g id="exit">
      <title>exit</title>
      <circle class="exitCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="144" fill="transparent"/>
      <path class="exitHover" d="m-143 0a143 143 0 1 1 286 0 143 143 0 0 1 -286 0m128-112a113 113 0 0 0 -97 97h97zm-97 127a113 113 0 0 0 97 97v-97zm127 97a113 113 0 0 0 97 -97h-97zm97-127a113 113 0 0 0 -97 -97v97z" transform="rotate(45)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>

<p>&lt;use&gt;</p>
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
    <use href="#exit" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to visit this link [[svg change color on hover]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157122/css-change-fill-color-on-hover-svg-path). It describes the solution that you may need.

Also, I am going to add the css of one button that I am using. When I hover on it the color is changed. Try to just use Button:hover and the css property of background-color.

```
button {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #b91d19;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/x4anrct0/8/)

On the example of jsfiddle

```
.thePlay:hover svg{
  fill:green;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/3uvkj97f/7/)

Comment: The X Button, not play Button. X Close Button

Comment: check first jsfiddle?